# Restrict Bigquery export to Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am currently exploring the GCP BigQuery IAM & Access Control.

The list of users can be managed through groups. Here's an example:

```
Group A - Has access to BigQuery (BigQuery User Role, Viewer Access to specific datasets)
Group B - Has bucket-owner access to Cloud Storage
```

Common users who are in both groups have the ability to export data from BigQuery to Cloud Storage. So, what is the best practice to deny exporting certain BigQuery tables or data that is larger than a certain number of rows, so transactional data exports are restricted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/datasets#dataset-acl), right now access controls can be applied to BigQuery datasets, but not to specific tables or views. Therefore, from a BigQuery perspective, your restrictions cannot be applied. Instead, you should use your own application to define the rules regarding the restrictions you seek.

However, given that the feature of restricting access to BigQuery tables and data with a big number of rows for exports, I have filed a feature request on your behalf as a Cloud Support representative. You can go to this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/109805342) to check this request and follow the progress that is being made through it. You can click on the star icon on the top left corner to enable notification that will be sent to you whenever any progress has been made.

Comment: I believe there is no way to restrict access to export through this process from bigquery if someone has an access to google storage linked with another project & big query linked with another project

Comment: As you say, there is no way right now to restrict the access to BigQuery tables and exports. There is a series of [roles](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control) currently available for different users, groups or service accounts. These roles are applied no matter whenever the user/group/service account is linked to a different project. The feature request I have opened on your behalf will help make what you wish possible in the future.